# Azure Event Grid subcriptions events to Splunk Endpoint

Tags: splunk, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to configure splunk url (https://xxxxxxxxxxx:8088/services/collector?token=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx) in event grid subscription as webhook endpoint type.
But i am getting error  ." Deployment has failed with the following error: {"code":"Url validation","message":"Webhook validation handshake failed for".
What is the correct process, does the splunk receives the logs ?

Does this work for splunk endpoints : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/receive-events. point me to the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

The error is expected as the webhook needs it needs to [validate the endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery#endpoint-validation-with-event-grid-events). As you are using splunk endpoint so your splunk needs to validate it. I believe you cannot write any code/logic for the validation event. So, you can search for the validation log on your splunk and the validation event will be as below:

[
{
"id": "2d1781af-3a4c-4d7c-bd0c-e34b19da4e66",
"topic": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"subject": "",
"data": {
"validationCode": "512d38b6-c7b8-40c8-89fe-f46f9e9622b6",
"validationUrl": "https://rp-eastus2.eventgrid.azure.net:553/eventsubscriptions/myeventsub/validate?id=0000000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000000&t=2022-10-28T04:23:35.1981776Z&apiVersion=2018-05-01-preview&token=1A1A1A1A"
},
"eventType": "Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent",
"eventTime": "2022-10-28T04:23:35.1981776Z",
"metadataVersion": "1",
"dataVersion": "1"
}
]

Once you find the above event in your logs you can copy the value of validationUrl property and open in the browser to initiate the webhook validation.

**Note :** The provided URL is valid for 5 minutes. During that time, the provisioning state of the event subscription is AwaitingManualAction. If you don't complete the manual validation within 5 minutes, the provisioning state is set to Failed. You'll have to create the event subscription again before starting the manual validation.